# File Movement on SFTP server

Tags: python, sftp

I am trying to execute a python script to move a file from a source to destination folder by adding timestamp using shutil and OS modules . I can execute the script fine when i use source and path files within same server. Seems like shutil function doesn't work to move/copy files when source/dest paths are from a SFTP server.

My requirement is to perform file movement on a SFTP server by executing script on a remote server.
Can this be achieved using Paramiko ?

Comment: first try to use `Paramiko` - and come back when you get error message.

Comment: where is your code? Where is Full error message which you get when you run it? We can't read in your mind - you have to show all information in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Answer (score -1):

All,

I was able to fix the issue. sftp_client.rename(src,dest) worked fine. I was using os.rename() earlier.